# ajax error response from content with IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

Could anybody help me to get the custom text from this result in IHttpresult

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Any object");
```

and show it in ajax error.

In server side I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CrearProducto(EProducto Producto)
{
    if (objBLProducto.ObtenerProductoRepetido(Producto, ConnectionStringStore).Count > 0)
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Producto repetido"); 
        if (objBLProducto.InsertarProducto(Producto, ConnectionStringStore))
        {
            return Ok(Producto);
        }
        else
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
}
```

and in my client side I have this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/API/Producto/",
        method: "POST",
        data: EProducto,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            toastr.success("Correcto");
        },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
})
```

And when the system detects a repited product It doesn't get the custom text (Producto repetido)

I hope anybody could help me, thanks.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
url: "/API/Producto/",
    method: "POST",
    data: EProducto, 
    dataType: "json", // return type of data from server - change it to text
    type: "POST",
    success: function () {
        toastr.success("Correcto");
    },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
```

})

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

for more detail please visit [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Do this on the server side:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
var errors = new List<string>();
errors.Add("Error 1");
//...more errors if any
return Json(errors);
```

On the client side:

```
.ajax(
{   //code...
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
      var errorData = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
      // Do whatever you need to
},
```

Comment: The response was catched by success part of json. Is there other way to pass get the custom message from server side to json error part?

Comment: You probably didn't set the response code as I have shown. If the server sends any status code different than 200, the error callback is executed